# How to exchange resources between resource pools in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I'm simulating a production line in Anylogic. At the moment I have three equal parallel lines that produces my products, they are not necessarily producing the same model at the same time.

[image: Image of the line].

The last process, called "MFT" is supposed to have dynamic resource behaviour, in case of necessity. Each MFT has a resource pool (Machines_MFT_L1, _L2 and _L3) and its default value is 4 (I can only have 12 machines in total, summing up the machines in all resource pools). In case, for example, a machine in the MFT of line one breaks, and the priority of production of line 1 is greater than the other lines, one of the other lines should send a machine to the resource pool of line 1. So, line 1 will have 4 machines + 1 repairing and the other line will have only 3 resources. When the machine that was repairing is repaired, it should be sent to the line that lent the extra machine to line 1 (the aim is always to reach the default value = 4 machines per resource pool).

How can this be done? the " machine" (agent) of my resource pools is called "jigs" and it's the same for the three pools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are, as usual, many ways to do this.

The simplest approach: just use the "set_capacity()" function on your resource pools. So if your MFT breaks, reduce the capacity on whichever pool you want by 1, and increase it accordingly in the other.

This way, you can make this as intelligent as you like, include priorities...